# Calling a variable from another function

Tags: python, function, error-handling

This is a simple example of the type of problem I have run into:

```
def making_list(text):
    list_ = []
    i = 0
    while i < int(len(text)):
        list_.append(text[i])
        i += 1
    return list_

def calling_list(list_):
    print list_

text = raw_input("text input")

making_list(text)
calling_list(list_)
```

The variable *list_*, which comes from **making_list**, is not recognized by the function **calling_list**. What is a possible solution to this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Note that `making_list(text)` is equivalent to `list(text)`. For example: `list("abcd") == ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

Comment: Indeed, in general, looping by index is a really bad idea in Python

Answer (score 3):

You're not storing the variable anywhere.

```
mylist = making_list(text)
calling_list(mylist)
```

Explanation: The variable names are valid only in scope of the function. If you leave function (with returning some local variable), you are returning only the 'value' of the variable, not it's name, you need to assign it to variable outside.

Comment: Calling variables `list` is a bad idea, you are smashing `list()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the variable that will take the output of `making_list` as its value. `making_list` function returns `list_`; but you can not reach it if you do not assign it to another variable out of your function.

`list_ = making_list(text)` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `making_list`-function doesn't return anything. This will work

```
list = making_list(text)
calling_list(list)
```

That will work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to change or optimize your code, I just want to give a possible solution:

1)If you want `list_` to be stored in memory, change the last 2 lines of your code like this:

```
list_=making_list(text)
calling_list(list_)
```

Now you can access list_ anywhere in your code.

2)If you don't want to store `list_` and you just want to print it and forget about it, delete the 2 last lines of your code and write this line instead:

```
calling_list(making_list(text))
```